# How to align the second child image first child image first line of images are going like steps

Tags: css

I am currently using this code which fixes the image next to the first image. But the third and forth image are not aligned with the first image. It is only the first line that has the problem. Images on the second line all line up correctly.

```
ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n)
{margin-top:-25px;}
```

When I use this code it fixes the image next to it but throws out the image in the second line.

Here below is a link to the page that has the issues.
http://www.secsa.co.za/fingerprint-readers/

Please can some point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inspected the issue area via developer tools, the problem may be resolved using `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap` assigned to `<ul>` containing product list and removing `margin-top:-25px` from the `li.product:nth-child(2n)`
This should fix the problem across all areas of your product list , you may refer to the link of video attached for better understanding:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1021817?key=a7eff6742ac925aa9179172b4e03772c

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw what you did with the web inspector tools and how to use the in web browser.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your Problem.

```css
ul.products {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It just made the images small but still going down in step form. Never helped with alignment.